# Store and Filter PHP array data with user input

Tags: php, ajax

Operator A:

734 | 6.9

89 | 0.14

8920 | 0.1

898 | 0.14

8931 | 0.14

8964   |   0.2

89643 | 1.1

Operator B:

9   |      0.67

66   |    0.5

89    |   0.2

896  |   1.0

23   |    1.2

And so on...
The left column represents the telephone prefix (country + area code) and the right column represents the operators price per minute for a number starting with that prefix. When several prefixes match the same number, the longest and cheapest one should be used. If you, for example, dial +89-64-321451 you will have to pay $ 1.1/min with Operator A and $ 1.0/min with Operator B, Operator B is the cheapest so it’s the best one.
If a price list does not include a certain prefix you cannot use that operator to dial numbers starting with that prefix. For example it is not possible to dial +66 numbers with operator A but it is possible with Operator B.
Please Help me to write a program that can handle any number of price lists (operators) and then can calculate which operator that is cheapest for a certain number. data must be store in PHP arrays. no SQL